# Why bow differently for Borachu and Amida?

Tags: tefilla

When bowing for three brachot in the Amida I've seen some people bend their knees. For Borachu I've seen those people do not bend the knees.  What is the logic or source underlying this difference in bowing?

Answer (score 2):

The practice is cited by *Eliyoh Rabbo* and *Mogen Avrohom* in the name of the *Zohar HaKodosh*. The *Zohar* distinguishes between the words *boruch* and *atoh*. A bending of the knees at *boruch* and a full bow at *atoh*. This only applies to the sequence *boruch atoh,* but for the other places *borechu es*, *boruch es*, and *modim anachnu loch,* the rule is to do a full bow immediately.

> **מגן אברהם קיג:ד** :
> כשיאמר ברוך יכרע בברכיו וכשיאמר אתה ישחה עד שיתפקקו החוליות [זוהר עקב של"ה] עכ"ל
>
> **אליה רבה קיג:ה** :
> כורע בברוך וכו'. כשאומר ברוך יעשה כריעה בברכים, וכשאומר אתה ישתחוה בראשו עד שיתפקקו וכו', פסקי תוס'. וכ"כ בזוהר פ' עקב [ח"ג רע"א ב]. כתב רש"ל בביאור סמ"ג [עמוד י]. ברוך הוא לשון ברך לך תכרע. ומשמע דבמודים ישחה גופו וראשו בבת אחת עכ"ל
>
> **זוהר רעיא מהימנא ח"ג פ' עקב רע"א ב** :
> ועל דא בצלותא ב"נ כורע בברוך דאיהו עלמא כפוף לגבי עילא ודא איהו שנוי בין ברוך דצלותא ובין ברוך דשאר ברכאן, וכלא ברזא עלאה איהו לארקא ברכאן לכל עלמין ברוך דצלותא ב"נ כורע ביה בברכוי וגחין רישא באתה בגין דאתה אקרי ראש

Comment: I don't see anything in the source indicating Attah is important or would be treated differently from Et or some other word

Comment: I added the text of the Zohar. Can't say I understand it, but there is the distinction between boruch and atoh. I believe that this is what the Eliyoh Rabbo is referring to when he writes that it seems that modim is different.

Comment: Point being, that before the Zohar, nobody seemed to bow their knees.